# Delete parent div when clicking link using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to fade out the parent 'content' div when clicking on either of the hyperlinks with the 'dc' class. The following code is what I already have, but does not work.

```
<script>
$('.dc').unbind("click").click(function(){
var dic = this.id;
var strlinkc = "somepage.php?cid=" + dic;
$.post(strlinkc, function(data, textStatus){
$('a.dc#'+dic).closest('.content').fadeOut("slow");
});
});
</script>

<div class="content">
<div id="somediv"><a class="dc" id="23" href="javascript:void(0);">update</a></div>
<div id="anotherdiv">
blah blah blah more text and images
</div>
<div id="yetanother"><a class="dc" id="23" href="javascript:void(0);">update</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: woah -- why is there a $.post() there?

Comment: Minor point: the div you mention is not the parent of the links you mention - it is an ancestor. This is why you're (correctly) using `closest()` rather than `parent()`.

Comment: the $.post() sends info to another page. After it sends the info, the content div is suppose to fadeout

Comment: Utkanos, you are correct sir, I should have put 'Delete parent div when clicking link using JQuery' as the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in dom ready handler.

```
$(function () {
    $('.dc').unbind("click").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var strlinkc = "somepage.php?cid=" + this.id;
        $.post(strlinkc, function (data, textStatus) {
            $this.closest('.content').fadeOut("slow");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.dc').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.content').fadeOut('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using unbind, prevent the default event.

```
$(function () {
    $('.dc').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var strlinkc = "somepage.php?cid=" + this.id;
        $.post(strlinkc, function (data, textStatus) {
            $this.closest('.content').fadeOut("slow");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```